# Fetch Current Month Sales in Qliksense

Tags: qliksense

I have Sales Register and i want to fetch the Current Month Sales & YTD in Qliksense On Basis of Invoice Date field in my excel data. 
So how to fetch the current month sales

Sample Date is given below

Invoice Date | Weight

01/04/2017 | 500

....

17/01/2018 | 250

On the above given data i need to find the MTD Sales & YTD Sales

Comment: its not quite clear what are you trying to achieve. Can you post more details? (and eventually data sample)

Comment: @StefanStoichev I have revised the question

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options - flags in the script and on the fly

**Flags in the script**

create two new fields `InMTD` and `InYTD`  with values `1` and `0` indicating if the record's `InvoceDate` is in MTD or YTD (the script below).

After having these two fields your expressions are quite straight forward:

```
= sum(  {< InMTD = { 1 } >}  Weight )
= sum(  {< InYTD = { 1 } >}  Weight )
```

The script uses [InMonthToDate](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2017/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/inmonthtodate.htm) and [InYearToDate](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2017/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/inyeartodate.htm) functions

```
Temp_Table:
Load
    InvoiceDate,
    // Create flag if the InvoceDate is in MTD based on Today() value
    InMonthToDate(InvoiceDateId, Today(), 0) * -1  as InMTD,
    // Create flag if the InvoceDate is in YTD based on Today() value   
    InYearToDate(InvoiceDateId, Today(), 0)  * -1  as InYTD,
    Weight
;
Load
    // Create number representation of the data field
    // which will be used in MTD and YTD calculations
    num(date(date#(InvoiceDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))) as InvoiceDateId, 
    InvoiceDate,
    Weight
;
// Load the actual data
Load * Inline [
    InvoiceDate , Weight
    01/04/2017  , 500
    10/01/2018  , 250
    12/01/2018  , 250
    13/01/2018  , 250
    17/01/2018  , 250
    19/01/2018  , 250
];
```

**On the fly**

Basically uses the same approach but everything is done in the expression

```
= sum( {< InvoiceDate = {">=$(=MonthStart(Today()))<=$(=Today())"} >}  Weight )
= sum( {< InvoiceDate = {">=$(=YearStart(Today()))<=$(=Today())"}  >}  Weight )
```

Example file can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pMRe9Tr_XAq2Tb8Bh3OliRq0M8mTciDK)